# How to get a specific value with in array using SQL

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I've the following array under a column 'X'. I'm trying to get task_due_date when task_type is 'sizeScale' using Spark SQL.

```
[{"task_type": "sizeScale", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}, {"task_type": "colorBreakdown", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}, {"task_type": "priceTicket", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}, {"task_type": "dcSplit", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}, {"task_type": "cartonLabel", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}]
```

I tried to explode the array to a separate table and join it to the original. Is there any other direct option?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
data = [[[{"task_type": "sizeScale", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}, {"task_type": "colorBreakdown", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}, {"task_type": "priceTicket", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}, {"task_type": "dcSplit", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}, {"task_type": "cartonLabel", "task_due_date": "2019-01-02"}]]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=["col_1"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("sample")
df = spark.sql("select columns_1.task_due_date from (select explode(col_1) as columns_1 from sample) where columns_1.task_type = 'sizeScale'")
df.show()
```

Output

```
+-------------+
|task_due_date|
+-------------+
|   2019-01-02|
+-------------+
```